# Ruby mongoid aggregation return object

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am doing an mongodb aggregation using mongoid, using `ModleName.collection.aggregate(pipeline)` . The value returned is an array and not a `Mongoid::Criteria`, so if a do a `first` on the array, I get the first element which is of the type `BSON::Document` instead of `ModelName`. As a result, I am unable to use it as a model.

Is there a method to return a criteria instead of an array from the aggregation, or convert a bson document to a model instance?

Using mongoid (4.0.0)

Comment: Can you show the query to think something else...?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this on my own too. I'm afraid you have to build your "models" on your own. Let's take an example from my code:

```
class Searcher
  # ...

  def results(page: 1, per_page: 50)
    pipeline = []

    pipeline << 
      "$match" => {
        title: /#{@params['query']}/i
      }
    }

    geoNear = {
      "near"               => coordinates,
      "distanceField"      => "distance",
      "distanceMultiplier" => 3959,
      "num"                => 500,
      "spherical"          => true,
    }

    pipeline << {
      "$geoNear" => geoNear
    }

    count = aggregate(pipeline).count

    pipeline << { "$skip" => ((page.to_i - 1) * per_page) }
    pipeline << { "$limit" => per_page }

    places_hash = aggregate(pipeline)

    places = places_hash.map { |attrs| Offer.new(attrs) { |o| o.new_record = false } }

    # ...

    places
  end

  def aggregate(pipeline)
    Offer.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
  end
end
```

I've omitted a lot of code from original project, just to present the way what I've been doing.

The most important thing here was the line:

```
places_hash.map { |attrs| Offer.new(attrs) { |o| o.new_record = false } }
```

Where both I'm creating an array of `Offers`, but additionally, manually I'm setting their `new_record` attribute to `false`, so they behave like any other documents get by simple `Offer.where(...)`.

It's not beautiful, but it worked for me, and I could take the best of whole Aggregation Framework!

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm hitting the same limitation too. In your example, you could use `Model::instantiate` instead of `new` to avoid having to deal with the `new_record` flag, e.g.: `places_hash.map { |attrs| Offer.instantiate(attrs) }`.

Comment: Hi @kardeiz, thanks for your hint! What do you mean by limitation? Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: The OP wanted to return a Mongoid::Criteria so he could continue chaining queries like how ActiveRecord::Relations works. The problem is aggregation returns an array. Consequently, there is no way to chain more scopes onto it. In your example, you use map which is very costly, imagine a million records.